# WPF DataGrid overlapping column

Tags: wpf, datagrid

The issue arises when I have disabled horizontal scrollbar (shown below) by using `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`, so all columns should fit.

I have 4 columns in my DataGrid. The first one has its `Width` set to `"*"`, while other 3 `Width` is `"Auto"`. There are buttons in the 3rd and 4th columns. The 3rd column contains two buttons one of which can has its `Visibility` set to `Collapsed`.

When first shown on the screen, two last columns with buttons overlap each other like shown in the picture below: [image: WPF DataGrid Glitch]

As you can see, there is more than enough space in the DataGrid.

If I resize the window or change the DataGrid's Visibility, next time it appears the columns will display properly.

Code:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectionUnit="FullRow" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" Margin="5">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Text" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Enabled" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Order" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Command="{Binding Data.MoveOptionUpCommand, Source={StaticResource BindingProxy}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                            <Image Source="/Resources/Images/Images16/Up.png" />
                        </Button>
                        <Button Command="{Binding Data.MoveOptionDownCommand, Source={StaticResource BindingProxy}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                            <Image Source="/Resources/Images/Images16/Down.png" />
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Actions" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Command="{Binding Data.ShowOptionEditAreaCommand, Source={StaticResource BindingProxy}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                            <Image Source="/Resources/Images/Images16/Edit.png" />
                        </Button>
                        <Button Command="{Binding Data.RemoveOptionsCommand, Source={StaticResource BindingProxy}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                            <Image Source="/Resources/Images/Images16/Remove.png" />
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Edit: added XAML code.**

Comment: Can you provide a code example of the issue along with the visual image? Creating a test wpf *proof of concept* project outside of the problem one, could lead you to the issue.

Comment: The trigger seems to be using data out the row's viewmodel. Have you considered altering the opacity of the disabled button rather than collapsing it?   I'd also be inclined to put the buttons in a stackpanel with fixed width columns rather than a stackpanel. Your icons could be paths instead of png. Using geometries in resources for iconography is more efficient than pictures, easier to switch out and re-use and they're vectors.

Comment: @Andy I tried to set Visibility to "Hidden" instead of "Collapsed", but the problem still persists. And what do you mean by "stackpanel with fixed width columns"? Did you mean Grid/UniformGrid? As for vector icons, you're right. I'll be switching to Paths once the application is at least in the Beta stage.

Comment: Oh.. I meant grid but somehow typed stackpanel twice. Alternatively, give the buttons a fixed width. I guess maybe your content (image and thus picture ) is driving the width at the moment.

Comment: @Andy Both Grid and UniformGrid with both "auto" and fixed width even made it worse. Not only column width was screwed, but even button height was about 5 pixels to the point that even the button icon wasn't visible.

Comment: Give the grid a height and width you like then. And remember the margin you have on your buttons this time.